# Seaborn subplotting

Tags: python, seaborn, subplot

I am working with the iris dataset.

I would like to plot, for each one of the four variables, in the dataset a violin plot and a boxplot per row.

```
variables=['SepalLengthCm','SepalWidthCm','PetalLengthCm','PetalWidthCm']

for var in variables:
    sns.boxplot(x = 'Species', y = var, data = iris)
    plt.show()
    sns.violinplot(x='Species', y=var, data= iris)
    plt.show()

sns.pairplot(iris, hue="Species")
plt.show()
```

I have used the code above and each figure appears in a row.

May somebody help me with the subplotting to order the figures and get a matrix 4(number of variables) x 2 (chars per variable)?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subplot for seaborn boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384040/subplot-for-seaborn-boxplot)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the subplot grid with `plt.subplots()`, assigning its axes to a variable, which is then a two-dimensional array (the dimensions corresponding to the rows and columns of the subplot grid). Then you can reference the respective sub-axes in the seaborn plot calls with the `ax` parameter.

Note that I'm using the original variables for convenience, and you only need to call `plt.show()` once, at the end.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
variables=['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=[10, 15])

for row, var in enumerate(variables):
    sns.boxplot(x='species', y=var, data=iris, ax=axes[row, 0])
    sns.violinplot(x='species', y=var, data=iris, ax=axes[row, 1])

plt.show()
```

[image: Iris data subplots]