# How to plot two different FacetGrids side by side

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization, histogram, facet-grid

Can I use a single FacetGrid object to plot two different types of plots side by side ?
I have tried plotting using two different FacetGrids but I can not get them side by side.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')
#dataframe.head()
```

This is what my dataset looks like.

[image: DATASET]

```
sns.FacetGrid(dataframe, hue = 'status', height = 5).map(sns.histplot, 'age').add_legend()
sns.FacetGrid(dataframe, hue = 'status', height = 5).map(sns.distplot, 'age').add_legend()
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Thank you.

Comment: Does [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41384984/16327476) help?

Comment: Use axes level plots and create a figure with subplots, as per the duplicate.

Comment: Yes, using subplots with sns.histplot() or sns.distplot() works but how will I make subplots work with FacetGrids ?

Comment: They do not work with FacetGrids